# Varien_Data_Form_Element_Int Not Found in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created a Magento attribute called sales_index. I have created the attribute to be an integer from the install script in the module I have created. This is what I have put into my install script:

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'sales_index', array(
    'input' => 'int',
    'type'  => 'int',
    'backend'   => '',
    'visible'   => 0,
    'required'  => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

The attribute seems to create correctly as no errors were given from the installer. However, when I move the sales_index attribute to the Default product attribute group and load one of the products in the admin panel I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_Int' not found in /var/www/vhosts/workingperson.com/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Abstract.php on line 129
```

So I figured I can just take this attribute out of the default attribute group and be fine. I am planning on setting this value in the background anyways. However, when I load a product, this value does not come along with it. The value is being set in the database, it just is not being loaded.

I am assuming that I did something wrong with creating the attribute that is not readily noticeable to me.

Does anyone know what I have to do to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `'input' => 'int'` line from your installer. I do not believe there is a separate form element type for integers, and the error lends onto the same.

Comment: Or change it to `'text'` if you want to see a text box on the product's edit page.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `'input' => 'int',` to `'input' => 'text',`. If this register is already on table, go to `eav_attribute` search for your row and change the field `frontend_input` to `text`.

This may to work.